# How to reside multi version of Oracle Client in DBD::Oracle on the same server

Tags: oracle, perl, perl-module

We have Oracle11gR1 and Oracle18c.

Perl clients(11.7.0.1) have to access to both version so far.

But Oracle client(11.7.0.1) were recommended to upgrade to new one(12.1.0.2)
according to Doc ID 207303.1  - 'Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix '

I'd like to hava 2 version of `DBD:Oracle` on the same clinet.
one for 11.7.0.1.
another for 12.1.0.2.
Because We can back to stable one immediately if new one caused problems.

How can I do that?
or
Impossible? Why?

I was successfully to install the following,

```
oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.i386.rpm  
oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.i386.rpm
```

After re-install `DBD::Oracle`,V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO shows them to '12.1.0.2'.that's I expected.

My Question is
How to switch back and force between 2 version of Oracle clinet of `DBD::Oracle` for just in case.
Because We can back to stable one immediataly if new one caused problems.

Ideally, By changing `$ORACLE_HOME` or `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` could be achieved I hope.
Otherwise, A lot of task will be needed like that changing $ORACLE_HOME or $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and re-complile `DBD:Oracle` to switch them in everytimes.

Does anyone have good advise?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Ideally, By changing $ORACLE_HOME or $LD_LIBRARY_PATH could be achieved I hope"* Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes ,I re-complie DBD:Oracle with 12.1.0.1 ,then I changed not only $ORACLE_HOME and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH i to 11.7.0.1.'s Path but also reboot it  .But V$CONNECT_INFO still shows 12.1.0.1.